# standard deviation of multiple columns and use them as them new columns

Tags: python, list, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe like the below example:

```
 mdata:
       id  f0   f1      f2  ..  fn         
       d1  dft  3       3   ..  5           
       d1  swe  7       4   ..  6           
       d1  rty  5       12  ..  3           
       d2  www  3       2   ..  5           
       d2  tot  1       4   ..  6           
       d2  asa  9       7   ..  9           
       ..   ..      ..  .. ..          
       dm   ..      ..  .. ..
```

I want to calculate the standard deviation and the average of the numerical columns for each unique id and use them as new columns. So the desired output should be like this:

```
 output:
       id  f0   f1   f1_std   f1_avg   f2   f2_std  f2_avg  ...    fn  fn_std  fn_avg   
       d1  dfd   3      2        5      3    4.93      6.3   ...     5   1.52    4.6 
       d1  swe   7      2        5      4    4.93      6.3   ...     6   1.52    4.6  
       d1  rty   5      2        5      12   4.93      6.3   ...     3   1.52    4.6  
       d2  www   3      4.16     4.3    2    2.51      4.3   ...     5   2.08    6.6
       d2  tot   1      4.16     4.3    4    2.51      4.3   ...     6   2.08    6.6 
       d2  asa   9      4.16     4.3    7    2.51      4.3   ...     9   2.08    6.6 
       ..   ..      ..   ..    ..      ..         ..    ...     ..   ..
       dm   ..      ..   ..    ..      ..         ..    ...     ..   ..
```

I am trying this code:

```
   mdata['f1_std']=mdata.groupby('id')['f0'].transform(lambda x: x.std(skipna=True, ddof=1))
```

But it works only for one feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something along the lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'f0':[3,7,5,3,1,9], 'f1':[3,4,12,2,4,7] , 'id':['d1','d1','d1','d2','d2', 'd2']})       

for column in ['f0','f1']:

    df[column+'_std']=df[['id',column]].groupby('id').transform(np.std)
```

return:

```
   f0  f1  id    f0_std    f1_std
0   3   3  d1  2.000000  4.932883
1   7   4  d1  2.000000  4.932883
2   5  12  d1  2.000000  4.932883
3   3   2  d2  4.163332  2.516611
4   1   4  d2  4.163332  2.516611
5   9   7  d2  4.163332  2.516611
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works also:

```
 newdata=mdata.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.std(skipna=True))
```